# Правильность транскрибирования текста

Tags: транскрипция

Затранскрибируйте текст. Определите количество лабиализованных и нелабиализованных согласных:

растём от года к году мы,
смотри, земля-старик, -
Садами и заводами
сменили пустыри.

[рΛст'óм от гóдΛ к    гóду мы/
смΛтр'и'/з'имл'á-стΛр'и'к/-
сΛдáм'и   и      зΛвóдъм'и
см'ин'и'л' и пустыр'и'//]

гласные лабиализованные: [у], [о];
гласные нелабиализованные: [и], [ы], [э], [а].

7 лабиализованных, 16 нелабиализованных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[рΛст'óм Λтгóдъ ггóду мы/(предлоги разбираются вместе с самостоятельной частью речи. К году-озвончение перед звонким Г)

смΛтр'и/з'и(с призвуком э)мл'á-стΛр'и'к/-

сΛдáм'и изΛвóдъм'и

см'и(с призвуком э)н'и'л'и пустыр'и//]

Я насчитала 6 лабиализованных, 17 нелабиализованных ГЛАСНЫХ, а не согласных.